# Want to access iPhone General Settings content in my App

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, jailbreak

I have iOS 7 jail-broken iPhone and I want to access about info (e.g settings -> General -> About). Actually I want to get IMEI and other stuff in about controller. Any clue guide will highly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure but Apple does not allow for privacy things to be used in app

Comment: @Macrosoft-Dev, Actually I m developing this app for cydia not for Appstore.

Answer (score 3):

MobileGestalt Library has a lot of information check it's header [here](https://github.com/Cykey/ios-reversed-headers/blob/master/MobileGestalt/MobileGestalt.h)

add this in your MakeFile

xxx_LIBRARIES = MobileGestalt

then declare:

```
OBJC_EXTERN CFStringRef MGCopyAnswer(CFStringRef key) WEAK_IMPORT_ATTRIBUTE;
```

in your Header file

then for getting the IMEI number you have to use :

```
CFStringRef IMEINumber = MGCopyAnswer(CFSTR("InternationalMobileEquipmentIdentity"));
NSLog (@"IMEI Number : %@", IMEINumber);
```

GoodLuck..

Comment: I have added header in my project when I compile code give me error that is  Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_MGCopyAnswer", referenced from:  . I m working on  iOS 7 and Xcode 5.0

Comment: did you add xxx_LIBRARIES = MobileGestalt to your makefile ? [ xxx ] is your tweak name ;)

Comment: Could you please explain what do you means by "xxx_LIBRARIES = MobileGestalt".

Comment: if you are using theos you should get MakeFile with the created project open it and add   YOURTWEAKNAME_LIBRARIES = MobileGestalt

Comment: I m not using theos. i have modified Xcode settings. Is there any alternative to resolve this error " Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_MGCopyAnswer", referenced from"

Comment: yes, there are go to Target ~> Build Phases ~> Link Binary With Libraries then Add libMobileGestalt.dylib GoodLuck ;)

Comment: libMobileGestalt.dylib make project error free but do not return IMEI. It returns NULL

Comment: yes because you are using a private header ;) you have to use it with mobile substrate ;) and it's your tour now ..

Comment: one more thing it won't work in simulator ;) just on jailbroken iDevices

Comment: Yes i am testing on jailbroken device. you said " have to use it with mobile substrate" what does this mean.

Comment: libMobileGestalt.dylib make project error " <~ can you show me this error ?

Comment: It gives compile time error which is "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_MGCopyAnswer""

Comment: mmmmm. did you add OBJC_EXTERN CFStringRef MGCopyAnswer(CFStringRef key) WEAK_IMPORT_ATTRIBUTE; in your header after '@end'

Comment: and here is a code for cydia tweak, [Here](https://ghostbin.com/paste/qpax4) which get your IMEI when you put your device in charge...

Comment: I m using xcode 5.0. As I import header file and run the it give me run time error (means do not compile). error comes in MobileGestalt.h line  "CFPropertyListRef MGCopyAnswer(CFStringRef property); it says CONFILICTING TYPES FOR MGCopyAnswer
"

Comment: OOOOOH SH*** LOL you have to remove MobileGestalt.h from your project it only for getting information.. and keep OBJC_EXTERN CFStringRef MGCopyAnswer(CFStringRef key) WEAK_IMPORT_ATTRIBUTE;

Comment: and you just use MobileGestalt.h for knowing information names and use it like imei just you have to change "InternationalMobileEquipmentIdentity" with any other information..

Comment: Is it possible that i access IMEI from its core location. I mean I just read plist or something like that where IMEI is stored.

Comment: thanks for your support. it works for other stuff like model unique id. but IMEI is still null.. why is this so

Comment: you are welcome... but, bad question,  do you test it on an iPad Wifi or iPod Touch :S LOL...

Comment: There are several ways to retrieve IMEI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667988/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone-5 But on iOS 7 they all require you to sign your app with `com.apple.coretelephony.Identity.get` entitlement.

Comment: @creker could please tell me that how should sign my app with com.apple.coretelephony.Identity.get entitlement. I m using Xcode 5.0.2 and iOS 7.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871748/how-do-i-change-my-applications-entitlements-to-com-apple-backboard-client