# How to get IMEI in iOS 7.1.2

Tags: xcode5, jailbreak, ios7.1, cydia

I have [code that is working fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667988/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone-5/16677043#16677043) till 7.0.6 to obtain **IMEI on Jailbreak iPhone**. But now I am getting null IMEI on my new **iPhone 4S** with **iOS 7.1.2**.

I have used **com.apple.coretelephony.Identity.get** entitlement and signing app with **ldid**. I am using Xcode 5.1.1.

Do I have to use any additional entitlement or something like that to obtain IMEI. Any suggestion or guide will highly appreciated Thanks

Comment: I have same problem and not find any suggestion.

Comment: Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667988/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone-5/16677043#16677043

Comment: Tried on my 7.1.2 5S - works. `com.apple.coretelephony.Identity.get` is the only entitlement it needs.

Comment: Its working on my iPhone 4 with 7.0.6  but doesn't work on 7.1.2 4S.

Comment: Any clue on this. Even i have the same issue.

Comment: Could you please upload preferences app binary from the phone that's not showing IMEI? Maybe there're new entilements. Otherwise I can't help you - on my 7.1.2 5S it works, the CoreTelephony one at least.

Comment: @creker here is link of preferences app binary. https://www.dropbox.com/s/8oi66ljtkbcf3bh/Preferences?dl=0

Comment: No, nothing new. I suggest you try to sign your app with every entitlement there is inside preferences binary (open it with text editor, at the end will be plist will entitlements). 
Also, which one of the solutions doesn't work? I use only CoreTelephony one.

Comment: @creker I have used **UIDevice-IOKitExtensions** mentioned in question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667988/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone-5/16677043#16677043. I have tried CoreTelephony, gonna try it once again ll update you. Many Thanks

Comment: @creker In CoreTelephony solution it says use of undeclared identifier on this line.    _CTServerConnectionCopyMobileEquipmentInfo(&result, connection, &info);

Comment: Read about Private APIs, how they work and how to use them. There's plenty of info. CoreTelephony solution works.

Comment: @creaker I do have CoreTelephony.h header file. But this method is not declare there. If You can provide me the declaration of this method _CTServerConnectionCopyMobileEquipmentInfo(&result, connection, &info);

Comment: https://github.com/RayZhang/EquipmentInfo/blob/master/UIDevice%2BCoreTelephonyCategory.m

Answer (score 0):

You can use libMobileGestalt which is the easiest way to do that.

just write this line after the import statement

```
OBJC_EXTERN CFStringRef MGCopyAnswer(CFStringRef key) WEAK_IMPORT_ATTRIBUTE;
```

then you can get the IMEI with

```
CFStringRef kMGInternationalMobileEquipmentIdentity = MGCopyAnswer(CFSTR("InternationalMobileEquipmentIdentity"));
```

And if you want to convert it to NSString..

```
NSString *IMEI = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",kMGInternationalMobileEquipmentIdentity];
```

Hope it helps