# How to get IMEI number programatically in swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uuid, serial-number, imei

I am making an iOS enterprise app which need iPhone/iPad IMEI, serial number and UUID programatically in Swift but I am not getting any way to find it out.

Apple doesn't allow us to get IMEI number directly but please let me know if any third party frameworks/api that provide me IMEI and other device information.

I don't want to upload app in App Store so there is no issue with Apple rejection.

Comment: While not in Swift, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667988/how-to-get-imei-on-iphone-5 for relevant info that should help.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Apple Developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/69009): you shouldn't try and get an user's IMEI programatically, as is violates Apple's privacy policy.

It'll also probably get rejected from the App Store. The only allowed way to get that information for app store apps is to ask the user to type it in.

However, if you're developing an enterprise application to be deployed on MDM devices, you can use an integration with your MDM provider to offer you that information.

Comment: Please read the last sentence of the question. Your first two paragraphs don't apply here.

Comment: Sure, they might not apply exactly, but they explain the rationale for _why_ there isn't a public API for this and are useful if anyone else stumbles into the question. The main point here is that there isn't a public API available for this.

Comment: If you read the question the OP already knows it's not public. And there are several duplicates covering trying to do this for the App Store. This question isn't a duplicate of those because the OP is specifically asking about doing this using non-public APIs for an app not going to the App Store. Your answer doesn't really apply to this question.